# What is this [4] doing there next to [review]?

Tags: support, review-page

I refreshed the page, but no change.  Note that there are no non-empty queues.

[image: scrshot]

Comment: have you recently voted on a question in any of the queues?  i have noticed that this extra flag remains unchanged if i vote on or skip something in a queue, and assumed that something is still open, just not for me.

Comment: I believe I have, though I don't quiet remember.  These things tend to enter my brain and then promptly leave to make room for other things :)

Comment: In addition to @barbarabeeton's comment, this are occasional [caching issues](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187216/168244), which may let review queue tallies linger longer than usual.

Answer (score 8):

Since you now have more than 10K reputation, the number in the status bar no longer displays the number of reviews in *your* queue, but the number of questions currently in *any* queue, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212225.

(This is in addition to the caching issue Werner pointed out, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266018.)