# A block badge Proofreader for my account

Tags: support, badges

I would to know if I have a problem with my account. Since a month I'm no longer eligible to accept or reject reviews since it has been changed the icons on this site. When I get a badge, the cup rarely becomes green and I do not see the badge achieved. In addition, the badges arrive very late. **Proofreader** seems stuck; I do not see the number to approve or reject the change. Is there a solution? I attach some picture of my account.

[image: There is blocked]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. When I visit the review queues, they work just as they did before, as far as I can tell. I have no idea about the badge thing as I don't know what I had before to compare. But the review stuff seems to work the same. I don't know what you mean about accepting or rejecting *reviews*, though. I've never had any such ability as far as I know.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173440/197238

Comment: @cfr Hi, I hope, now, to understand me.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the link. But why I not see the number of review of as before?

Comment: I have no idea: there is no record of anything changing as far as I can see, are you sure it is different?

Comment: The proof-reader badge is for completing reviews (i.e. being active) their in the 'Suggested Edits' queue. Skipping reviews doesn't count of course. The new top bar however is 'difficult' as it does not tell you that there are reviews. (other than the orange 'bar' in previous versions) -- it is necessary to click on the review button in order to see whether there are reviews, here in the Suggested Edits Queue

Comment: Typo: I meant 'there', not 'their', of course -- sorry about that.

Answer (score 4):

There used to be [a number written in the top navigation bar](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4628/5764) to identify the number of reviews available to the user. However, this was [not always accurate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187216/168244) with the blame put on caching.

The [new top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300829/168244) now puts a silver bullet next to an item when there's *some* items to review; here's a view from the Stack Overflow top bar:

[image]

Once a queue has an *extreme* number of items in it, the silver bullet turns red, and it also lights up on the review button in the toolbar:

[image]

The new top bar [doesn't fix the caching problem just yet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300864/168244), but it's apparently an improvement.

---

If you are unsure when last you may have received some badge, you can follow the click sequence [User profile > Activity > all actions > badges and see when you received what:

[image]

Comment: ...not sure whether this answers your question.

Comment: `Once a queue has an extreme number of items in it, the silver bullet turns red, and it also lights up on the review button in the toolbar.` -- Apparently one item in the review queue is considered `extreme` this since, since there was a red bullet this morning and one single item to review (in Suggested Edits) ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Yes; one extreme review queue lights up the review icon with a red bullet.

Comment: I understood that, but the number of items in that specific queue was just one item, if I remember correctly